# Is it possible to skip all the items in a particular review queue?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to skip all the items in a review queue.

I have more than 700+ items in a review queue and per day we are allowed to review only 20 posts. So there is no point in keep them in my review queue.

Comment: Why would you want to skip *all*? If you want to access a specific post, just go to its page and edit/flag/close. No matter whether you skip or not, you review 20 per queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot skip these items, though you are limited to 20 per day. The point is to clear as many as you can in each day. The list just shows you how many remain overall.

Comment: Are you saying everyone's review queue shows the same number of posts remaining??

Comment: @EliahKagan not exactly. It shows the number of posts remaining for everyone minus what you've covered already. Sorry for not making that clearer. The difference (as far as I Know) is with close votes. Close votes only show if you have votes left.